# Change vim-airline colorscheme via vim-sunset plugin

Tags: vim, autocmd, vim-airline

I just recently discovered two VIM plugins that I find very useful, namely vim-sunset (http://vimawesome.com/plugin/sunset) and vim-airline (http://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-airline-sad-beautiful-tragic).
Changing the colorscheme with vim-sunset was easy, but I would like it to also change the colors in my airline.
I have tried to achieve this via

```html
function! Sunset_daytime_callback()
  
  " Version 1
  let g:airline_theme = 'airline_theme_light'

  " Version 2
  colorscheme vim_colorscheme_light
  autocmd ColorScheme * :AirlineTheme airline_theme_light
  
  " Version 3
  autocmd ColorScheme * :AirlineTheme airline_theme_light
  colorscheme vim_colorscheme_light
  
endfunction
```

(same thing for `Sunset_nighttime_callback()`)

The problems are the following:

- Version 1: I guess the variable `airline_theme` is correctly set, but it doesn't update. Also, I couldn't find any function in the airline documentation mentioning how to "redraw" with the new parameters.
- Version 2: This kind of works, but I have to call the function  `Sunset_daytime_callback()` twice in order to update the powerline too
- Version 3: Breaks because the plugin command `:AirlineTheme` is not ready yet when the `.vimrc` is first executed

Is there a (possibly elegant) solution how to get this to work? Did I maybe just miss a function in the airline plugin that just redraws the line?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution myself: the key is to check whether or not the airline-plugin is already loaded when trying to set the airline colorscheme.
Now it looks something like this:

```html
function! Sunset_daytime_callback()

  " This Works :)
  colorscheme vim_colorscheme_light
  if exists(':AirlineTheme') " check if the plugin is loaded
      :AirlineTheme light
  else
      let g:airline_theme = 'light'
  endif

endfunction
```